# Printing JSON output from API

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I'm facing issues while printing JSON data using jQuery.

JSON Output:

```
[
{"id":"1", "product_name":"banana", "price":"10"},
{"id":"2", "product_name":"apple", "price":"15"},
{"id":"3", "product_name":"pineapple", "price":"20"}
]
```

I used `getJSON()` to retrieve data from JSON output of the API.

To print the JSON output, I used jQuery:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
   $('p').append(key + ':' + value);
});
```

The above code doesn't seem to output anything.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: your json is invalid try to parse [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and check again

Comment: DKM is correct, you need double quotes in json for strings (your id and price can also be plain numbers without any quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your date already appears to be JSON, so you shouldn't need `$.parseJSON(data);`. You are looping over each item of the array. Each item of the array is an object, so you then need to iterate over each of the object's properties also: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/afaXosOt/1/edit)**

```
var data = [
  {
    "id":"1", 
    "product_name":"banana",
    "price":"10"
  },
  {
    "id":"2", 
    "product_name":"apple", 
    "price":"15"
  },
  {
    "id":"3", 
    "product_name":"pineapple", 
    "price":"20"
  }
];

$.each( data, function(i, obj) {
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
   $('p').append(key + ':' + value);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly , your JSON isn't valid...
secondly, you don't need to parse your JSON if your are using `getJSON()` and the server response is in JSON correctly..remove that line and it should work

try this

```
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
  $('p').append(key + ':' + value);
});
```

Comment: I removed the parse to json and this is the output I get `0:[object Object]1:[object Object]2:[object Object]`